# What does "zo <=500Ω" on the pin diagram means?

Tags: led, pins, diagram

There is device (viewfinder). It has "Tally" LED. On the camera's output diagram, on the "Tally OUT Indicator" pin there is marking "zo <=500Ω". What does it mean? Should I supply + voltage on this pin with 500Ω resistor?

[image]

Comment: http://www.dvinfo.net/forum/attachments/open-dv-discussion/19171d1282141328-panasonic-dvcpro-viewfinder-pinout-sony20pinviewfinderdxf801.jpg
pins 3 and 4

Answer (score 1):

It means that the output impedance is less than or equal to 500 ohms.

If you connect an external circuit with an impedance of say 200 ohms then the voltage you will get will be only 2/7 of what you expect. Therefore you may need to use a circuit with a high input impedance in order to get a usable voltage.

Comment: Not quite, it means that with a 200 ohm load the voltage you get will be 2/7 of nominal **or higher**. The output impedance may be much lower than the worst case figure, so don't rely on it if you need to attenuate the output.

Comment: but what does it say about the voltage of the led that will be connected to this output?..

Comment: Absolutely nothing.